# Handsontable: Jumping to the start of the next row when a row is completed

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable in order to allow people to input data. I want them to either use tab or enter when they are done with a cell, hitting these keys whenever they are done filling a cell.

When a row is completed, they would obviously use enter too, kind of like a typewriter. However, they don't jump to the first cell in the next row.

I can configure this with the `enterMoves` option:

```
    minSpareCols: 0,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    enterMoves: {row: 0, col: 1}
```

According to one person on GitHub, [this feature should be in the main code](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/68):

> I implemented your suggestion into core :) Please use the following
>   set of params and let me know what you think:
>
> ```
> minSpareCols: 0, 
> enterMoves: {row: 0, col: 1}
> ```

[Here's a JSFiddle with my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/s6t768pq/971/)

I filled a row with data and pressing enter does nothing.

[image: handsontable image]

Is there any way to enable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [AMBudnik on Github](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/4531), this question has received a solution:

> `enterMoves` can be a functions as well, so you can determine how to
>   move when selection reaches the last column.
>
> [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtfam5v1/) where I move the
>   selection one column right and after we reach the last column we pick
>   the first cell in the next row.